# What are some examples of these kinds of commutative semirings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

What are some examples of commutative semirings such that the following hold?

1. Multiplication is idempotent i.e. we have $xx=x$ for all elements $x$.
2. Addition is not idempotent i.e. there is at least one element $x$ with $x+x \neq x$.
3. There is at least one element $x$ with $x+x \neq 0$.

I cannot think of any examples, with or without commutativity.

*Discussion.* In ring theory, it is a theorem that if multiplication is idempotent, then $x+x=0$ for all elements $x$. However, in semiring theory, this isn't necessarily the case; take, in particular, any non-trivial distributive lattice. Then it is certainly the case that $x+x \neq 0$ for all $x,$ except $x=0$ of course. In fact, we have that $x+x=x$ for all elements $x$.

Comment: What do you mean with "multiplication is idempotent"? That **all** the elements of the ring are idempotent, or what? Also, in *any* ring, $\;x+x=x\iff x=0\;$, so if abide by the usual convention thaty $\;0\neq 1\;$ then there is no counter example here. The last condition is true whenever the characteristic of the ring isn't two.

Comment: @Timbuc: Read "semiring"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial semiring is $\mathbb{N}$ (with the usual operations). Hence, the initial boolean semiring is $R = \mathbb{N} / \sim$, where $\sim$ is the smallest congruence relation such that $n \sim n^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, we also have $n_1^2 + \dotsc + n_s^2 \sim n_1 + \dotsc + n_s$. The elements of $R$ are therefore
$$[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]=[2],[5]=[3],[6]=[2],[7]=[3],\dotsc$$
We find that $R$ is actually finite, it has exactly $4$ elements. This ring satisfies your requirements.

Another example is the free boolean semiring on one generator $x$. It is given by $\{a+bx : a,b \in R\}$ modulo the relation $a+bx \sim (a+bx)^2 = (a+b)+(2ab)x$. This semiring is also finite and its elements may be listed explicitly, if one wants to.